# Redis Search offset limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm trying to get Redis items from a Redis search (ft.search) in small batches not to run out of memory in the client side (The queries are typically 40k or 50k items). To do so I'm playing with the LIMIT by accumulating the offset and querying for a fixed number of items (which i think is called paging). The problem arises when I arrive at the offset 10000.

At this point the queue returns undefined.

I have investigated the result in the command-line by using

```bash
ft.search idx:cits "*" LIMIT 10000 10
```

and instead of returning 10 elements, it returns

```bash
1) (integer) 42955
```

I also tried

```bash
ft.search idx:cits "*" LIMIT 10001 10
```

which weirdly enough returns

```bash
(error) OFFSET exceeds maximum of 10000
```

So it seems my problem is that the offset is a maximum of 10000. Is there any way to change this offset limit from the JavaScript code? Is there any way to change this limit from the Redis config? Otherwise, how could I overcome this limitation?

I leave here a minimal code to reproduce my problem,

```js
const { createClient, SchemaFieldTypes } = require('redis')

const client = createClient()

async function start(client) {
    await client.connect()
    try {
        // We only want to sort by these 3 values
        await client.ft.create(
            'idx:cits',
            {
                mid: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.TAG
                },
                timestamp: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.NUMERIC,
                    sortable: true
                },
                position: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.GEO
                }
            },
            {
                ON: 'HASH',
                PREFIX: 'CITS'
            }
        )
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message === 'Index already exists') {
            console.log('Skipping index creation as it already exists.')
        } else {
            console.error(e)
            process.exit(1)
        }
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < 45000; index++) {
        await client.hSet(`CITS:${index}:0:0:00:00:5e:00:53:af`, {
            timestamp: index,
            position: '0,0',
            mid: '00:00:5e:00:53:af',
            message: 'payload'
        })
    }

    try {
        let results = await client.ft.search(
            'idx:cits',
            '@mid:{00\\:00\\:5e\\:00\\:53\\:af}',
            { LIMIT: { from: 10000, size: 10 } }
        )
        console.log(results)
        results = await client.ft.search(
            'idx:cits',
            '@mid:{00\\:00\\:5e\\:00\\:53\\:af}',
            { LIMIT: { from: 10001, size: 10 } }
        )
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

    await client.quit()
}
start(client)
```

Does the [cursor API](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/aggregations/#cursor-api) have the same limitation? How many items can a cursor refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bt default, RediSearch limits the maximum number of search results to 10,000. You can override this behavior by using the FT.CONFIG SET command and changing the MAXSEARCHRESULTS value. Setting it to -1 removes the limit.

```bash
redis.cloud> FT.CONFIG SET MAXSEARCHRESULTS -1
```

Details on all the config options for RediSearch can be found [here](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/configuring/).

Comment: Thanks!, Does disabling the limit impact the performance in any way? What about the cursors API would it be more suitable for this scenario?

Comment: **Update**: When using your solution, after setting the MAXSEARCHRESULTS to -1 using `redisClient.ft.CONFIG_SET('MAXSEARCHRESULTS', '-1')` and querying with an offset higher than 10000 the Redis server immediately crashes. I'm currently using the docker redis/redis-stack:6.2.6-rc1 image to run  it.

Comment: The -1 setting might be for a newer version. Perhaps try setting it to a large number than you expect to need?

Comment: It won't affect performance per se, but it's not really a cursor. If you time the calls, each subsequent page of results will take proportionally longer. Behind the scenes, RediSearch is just getting the first page, then the first 2 pages, then the first 3 pages, etc. and returning the last page.

Comment: Using the new redis-stack 7.0.6-RC2 images resolves the crash. Thanks!